# Make Bluemix App Faster

Tags: performance, time, server, load, ibm-cloud

I have recently deployed my app to Bluemix. Currently, the settings are 256mb of Memory and 1 instance. What would you suggest increasing/altering to get better performance? Right now the main page takes 8-15 seconds to load and ajax calls take at least 5 seconds. The app is pretty intensive on HTTP requests (ajax calls), however the calls themselves are relatively simple scripts. I'm just looking for some guidence on what I should change and what I should change it to to see better performance.

Thank you,

--

EDIT:

The front-end of the app is written in React.js and some jQuery. The backend is PHP and mustache (for the views) and we use SQL. Most of the AJAX requests are handled by React.js—it makes varying-sized JSON requests.

Comment: You need to provide more details on the app, its architecture, and what kind of requests it makes in the background. Then it is possible to discuss caching strategies, code optimization, network configuration, resource assignment, etc.

Comment: @data_henrik Thanks for the response, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think increasing your memory or instances will have much effect on your UI performance if the bottleneck is your AJAX request response times.

Use your browser Developer Tools to monitor the Network Activity tab. See which of your AJAX requests are taking the longest time to respond and tackle those first. Confirm you aren't forcing no-cache. Avoid calling the same URL multiple times - instead, save the result in javascript and reuse.

Database queries tend to be the bottleneck for most applications. Use caching services like Bluemix Data Cache or an in memory cache to avoid going to a database multiple times per request.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to attack two ways.

- Bluemix server side
- Network side

Bluemix server side
 Since your are running 256MB memory, it may hit memory problem.
http://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/ui/
 There is a plugin to monitor your application. By this, you can monitor application CPU and memory usage during your test. Refer to this page for more detail:  https://github.com/danhigham/cf-live-stats

Network side
 Bluemix is hosted in USA/UK/Australia. There is significant latency if you are living outside of these countries. Looks like there are many calls (ajax), latency might be a problem. Try to check using network traffic monitor tool (e.g. BuzZilla, or HttpWatch basic edition). If this was the case. Your application needs tweeks not to call server logic frequently.

Anyway, the first you need to try is monitor server and network.

Comment: Thank you for the response! We're in Southern USA, so latency shouldn't be too big an issue here. What is the service called inside the Bluemix dashboard that can be used to monitor it?

Comment: Hi 
Live-Stat is Cloud Foundry command line interface plugin.  Alternatively, you can do manually. For example, obtain guid of your application by 

`$ cf app <yourapp> --guid 
<guid will be print out here>`


And them, run 


`$ cf curl /v2/apps/<:guid>/stats`


It will give a usage like this:



`         "usage": {
            "time": "2015-12-11 01:22:07 +0000",
            "cpu": 0.0,
            "mem": 62070784,
            "disk": 63811584
`